# Searching for an element in a list with a loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, search

I've been having some trouble finding if an element is already stored in a list in a Python code. I've used two scripts. The second one I wrote turned out to work, but the first one didn't and I don't understand why (and it's bothering me). The list I have is called `grains` and looks like this :
`[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], ...]`.

Here is the first piece of code, not working :

```
for i in range(0, len(grains) - 1) :
    if grains[i] == [x,y] :
        return
    else :
        grains.append([x,y])
        grains_restants = grains_restants - 1
        fourmi_chargee = False
        return
```

And here is the second piece of code, this one works :

```
if not([x,y] in grains) :
    grains.append([x,y])
    grains_restants = grains_restants - 1
    fourmi_chargee = False
    return
```

So I tried to understand why the first piece of code doesn't work, but I gave up. Do you know why ?

Comment: what is the value of `a`, `b` in `grains`? what is the value of `x` and `y`?

Comment: `range`'s parameters are `inclusive, exclusive`  - that means it will include the first number you give it, and go all the way up to but not including, the second number. Hence, you never actually access the last element in your for loop.

Comment: Because in your first piece of code it'll only compare `grains[0] == [x, y]`, and then the `for` loop will `return` either it's `True` or `False`.

Comment: also, if your list example is correct, there shouldn't be an element `[x,y]` in your list. Instead, there should be `[w, x]` and `['y, z]`.

Comment: You probably want a `set` instead of a `list`

Comment: @PauloScardine Good idea, except it'd have to be a set of tuples, not lists, because set items _must_ be completely immutable. So if `a`, `b`, etc aren't immutable, we can't make a set, even if we put those items into tuples. (Also, a set is no good if the pairs aren't unique, or if we need to preserve order.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first piece of code will not loop list `grains` as your expectation, it'll actually only compare `grains[0] == [x, y]` and the `for` loop will exit due to you have `return` in either `if` and `else` branch, while the second implementation will check whether `[x, y]` is in the whole list `grains` or not.

You should **NOT** use code like this but the `for` loop code is supposed to be:

```
for i in grains:
    if i == [x,y] :
        break
else:
    grains.append([x,y])
    grains_restants = grains_restants - 1
    fourmi_chargee = False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0, len(grains) - 1) :
    if grains[i] == [x,y] :
        return
    else :
        grains.append([x,y])
        grains_restants = grains_restants - 1
        fourmi_chargee = False
        return
```

You are matching every element in the list against `[x,y]` but you really want to check if `[x,y]` exists already. That's what the 2nd code snippet does using the `in` operator.

Now why does the first one not work? You didn't mention what errors / unexpected scenarios you were getting but I can see one. Let's assume that the `[x,y]` element is in index 3 (4th item). But you're comparing it to 0,1,2 => all of them won't match and add a duplicate item and then return. That's really not what you want.

To check if the element exists, using the `in` operator is the best idea. You could also use `list.count` to see if any element exists in the list (and how many times it appears in that list).